# What controls whether CocoaPods shows a landing page or just links to a Git Repo?

Tags: cocoapods

We have several Pods hosted on CocoaPods. When browsing those pods on CocoaPods, clicking the link will sometimes take us to a landing page containing the README and a CHANGELOG. However, for some other pods, clicking the link will just take us to the Git repo for the pod.

I couldn't find any documentation on how things must be configured to ensure a landing page for a Pod.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the landing page READMEs and CHANGELOGs are stuck at their March 2021 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check again.

A bug that had been preventing README and CHANGELOG updates for the last several months was fixed today.

Details in https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-metadata-service/issues/22

If you're still seeing issues, file another issue at https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-metadata-service/issues